# Open CV - (python) - Rough Template matching

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ros

So Im looking to try and find basic shapes within an image i'm getting from my camera.
I've found lots of helpful stuff on finding squares, triangles and other simple shapes. But Im struggling with looking for a specific shape.
At the bottom of the picture is a shape i'll refer to as a "bridge"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsc4G.png

Id love a way to search the image and find a match with the following "template" image: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWAyO.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Ideally Python!)
Thanks

Comment: will both, template and roughly equal-shaped object(s) have the same size/orientation etc?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the template matching tutorial at http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html ? Looks pretty useful to me :)

Comment: They will have roughly the same orientation yes, as in, they wont be upside-down. but size could vary. The tutorial seems to be for exact matching, Not "really rough matching"